# Koszul algebra and Hilbert series

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-rings

$A$ is a Koszul algebra. Its Hilbert series $h(z)=1+az+bz^2$. Prove that $h(z)$ has real roots.

I know that $A=A_0\oplus A_1\oplus A_2$ and $\dim A_1=a$, $\dim A_2=b$.
And it's needed to prove that $a^2\geqslant 4b$.
But don't know how to prove it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is A commutative?

Comment: actually, not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is proved, for example, in Theorem $3.1$ on page $207$ in the paper [Koszul property for points in projective spaces](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24491957?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). There it is proved that for the Hilbert series $1+nz+mz^2$ we have Koszulness if and only if $m\le \frac{n^2}{4}$. In the proof it is used that the coefficients of the series
$\frac{1}{h(-z)}$ are positive in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I can't undestand in thrm 3.1 why 2) implies 3). Could you tell me this?

Comment: Because of equation $(1)$.